# How to write pow( ) in swift and fix errors?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a pow function in swift and this is my code:

```
var recorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var levelTimer = NSTimer()
var lowPassResults: Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("dev/null")
    //numbers are automatically wrapped into NSNumber objects, so I simplified that to [NSString : NSNumber]
    var settings : [NSString : NSNumber ] = [AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0, AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue]
    var error: NSError?
    self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL, settings:recordSettings, error:&error];
    if((recorder) != nil){
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.meteringEnabled = true
        recorder.record()
        levelTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.03, target: self, selector: Selector("listenForBlow"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else{
        NSLog("%@", "Fehler an dieser Stelle");
    }
}
func levelTimerCallback(timer:NSTimer) {
    recorder.updateMeters()
    let ALPHA: Double = 0.05
    var peakPowerForChannel: Double = pow(10, (0.05 * [self.recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)]))
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

    NSLog("@Average input: %f Peak input: %f Low pass results: %f", [recorder.averagePowerForChannel(0)], [recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)], lowPassResults);
}
```

I'm getting errors in two lines and I don't know how to fix them.
This is the first error in this line: (error: "Expected ',' separator). Is there a syntax error which I overlooked?

```
self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL, settings:recordSettings, error:&error];
```

This is the other error:"Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments". I know that the types must be the same (Double * Double). But where exactly is the mistake?

```
var peakPowerForChannel: Double = pow(10, (0.05 * [self.recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)]))
```

P.S.: I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I can not find a answer in swift. Thanks ahead!!

Comment: It looks like you pasted Objective-C code into a Swift file. I think you want to use `recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL:…settings:…)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Swift, not Objective-C, syntax to initialize your audio recorder:

```
recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL:…settings:…)
```

For calculating `peakPowerForChannel`, know that `10` will be an `Int` and `peakPowerForChannel(_:)` returns `Float`, not `Double`. You'll need to explicitly cast these:

```
var peakPowerForChannel : Double = pow(Double(10), (0.05 * Double(recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))))
```

Also, since `pow(_: _:)` returns `Double`, you can delete `peakPowerForChannel`'s type specification:

```
var peakPowerForChannel = pow(Double(10), (0.05 * Double(recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))))
```